# Replacing multiple strings in a word doc in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, replace, ms-word

I'm trying to replace multiple strings in a word document using PowerShell, but only one string is replaced when running the code below:

```
#Includes
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

#Functions
#Function to find and replace in a word document
function FindAndReplace($objSelection, $findText,$replaceWith){
    $matchCase = $true
    $matchWholeWord = $true
    $matchWildcards = $false
    $matchSoundsLike = $false
    $matchAllWordForms = $false
    $forward = $true
    $wrap = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdFindWrap]::wdReplaceAll
    $format = $false
    $replace = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdFindWrap]::wdFindContinue
    $objSelection.Find.Execute($findText,$matchCase,$matchWholeWord,$matchWildcards,$matchSoundsLike,$matchAllWordForms,$forward,$wrap,$format,$replaceWith, $replace)  > $null
}

$item1 = "Should"
$item2 = "this"
$item3 = "work"
$item4 = "?"
$fileName = "NewFile"

#Opens a file browsers to select a word document
$FileBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog -Property @{
    InitialDirectory = [Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')
    Filter = 'Documents (*.docx)|*.docx'
}

Write-Host "Select word template file"
$FileBrowser.ShowDialog()
$templateFile = $FileBrowser.FileName
$word = New-Object -comobject Word.Application 
$word.Visible = $false
$template = $word.Documents.Open($templateFile)
$selection = $template.ActiveWindow.Selection

FindAndReplace $selection '#ITEM1#' $item1
FindAndReplace $selection '#ITEM2#' $item2
FindAndReplace $selection '#ITEM3#' $item3
FindAndReplace $selection '#ITEM4#' $item4

$fileName = $fileName
$template.SaveAs($fileName)
$word.Quit()
```

If I comment out FindAndReplace the first one that runs works, but subsequent calls do not.

For example running this as is results in:

```
Input              Output
#ITEM1#            Should
#ITEM2#            #ITEM2#
#ITEM3#            #ITEM3#
#ITEM4#            #ITEM4#
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing, any help would be appreciated

Comment: I would assume it is related to `$forward = $true`. After your first find/replace, the cursor is positioned at the bottom. I'm not up-to-speed with Word automation but I assume it should be possible to wrap your search around and/or position the cursor back at the top. Either should work.

Comment: Thank You, that didn't work for me but your insight lead me to answer that did. There may be a more elegant solution but I'll post what worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

As was suggested it appears that the cursor was not returning to the beginning of the document. I added the following code:

```
Set-Variable -Name wdGoToLine -Value 3 -Option Constant
Set-Variable -Name wdGoToAbsolute -Value 1 -Option Constant
```

To the beginning of my script and:

```
$objSelection.GoTo($wdGoToLine, $wdGoToAbsolute, 1) > $null
```

as the first line in my FindAndReplace function, and now it works as expected.

There may be a more elegant solution, but this works for me